# The precision and recall generated from the ROUGE score

Tags: precision, summarize, precision-recall, summarization, rouge

I calculated precision and recall from the F1-score, specifically for the ROUGE-1 metric.

The ROUGE score is an evaluation metric that compares the generated summary to a reference summary to calculate the overlap between the two in terms of n-gram, word sequences, and word pairs.

The precision and recall generated from the ROUGE score is going beyond 1. generally, precesion-recall can't exceed 1, but here i am getting for some reading 1. something.
is it ok or something is wrong? any one having any idea please share.
Thank you!!